# Library for android for image processing

Tags: android, android-library

I have been searching everywhere for suitable android library.
I need to extract number from a photo, to be more specific
I have to take a photo of the bill and get its serial number.
What kind of library should I use ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [tesseract-android-tools](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/) (bindings of Tesseract OCR for Android).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , there is no such Library available in Android. You might need to code for your self for it. However such type of Scanner is available in Nokia E5 phone, I have seen it in my friend's Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ron Cemer's Java OCR library](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr). to extract text from picture

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android, OpenCV is the best library for image processing in Android...